# Getting an error while trying to pull git Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I am working with a colleague on a project in Xcode. He committed and pushed some changes. Before fetching and refreshing status, I committed and pushed my changes too...

What I've tried so far:

- To pull and rebase local changes onto upstream changes.
- Then I stash and pull. But get "An unknown error occurred".

So, basically my git has these arrows down and up: 
[Xcode. Git situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HavMu.png)

Since it's an important project, I don't know if I should do a force push.. Any ideas on how I can resolve it correctly?

UPDATE: 
I tried writing `git pull` in Console and here is what I've got:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

And this is the message I get when I try to `git push`:

```
 ! [rejected]        branch -> branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:***'
```

Comment: The error you are getting from `git pull` seems pretty self-explanatory. You are going to have to move the untracked files out of the way, since it seems like the upstream repo has files with the same name. After you've pulled you can move the untracked files back.

Comment: Also, never do a force push unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Rudedog! 
How do I move them out of the way exactly?

Comment: Just move them somewhere else. I assume you know how to manage files with Finder.